# iTextSharp Append Page If PDF Exists Using Stamper

Tags: c#, itext

I am using the following method to take 2 PDFs (CADPDF & TemplatePDF, and superimpose them as another pdf (FinalPDF).

```
public void MergePDFs(string CADPDF, string TemplatePDF, string FinalPDF, string oldData, string newData, string jobNumber, string customer, string designer, string date)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(TemplatePDF);
        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(CADPDF);

        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(FinalPDF, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));

        PSModel psModel = powerSHAPE.ActiveModel;

        try
        {

            AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

            fields.SetField("oldDataField", oldData);
            fields.SetField("newDataField", newData);
            fields.SetField("jobNumberField", jobNumber);
            fields.SetField("customerField", customer);
            fields.SetField("dateField", date);
            fields.SetField("designerField", designer);
            stamper.FormFlattening = false;

            PdfImportedPage page = stamper.GetImportedPage(reader2, 1);
            PdfContentByte cb;

            cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height);

            stamper.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Unable to merge drawing with template!");
        }

        stamper.Close();



    }
```

Everything works nicely, but now i need to append another page if this FinalPDF already exists. I have changed the FileStream's FileMode to Append, but the FinalPDF is overwritten instead of appended.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: `FileMode.Append` is wrong of course. iText's output always is the whole result file. As soon as there is anything more than a zero length file at the result position, `FileMode.Append` will result in an invalid PDF (whether or not Adobe Reader recognizes it, is a different matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the best results with iTextSharp by using memory streams and byte[] arrays.   I generate a blank PDF using the PdfSmartCopy class and then retrieve the required elements as byte[] from the different sources.

Use the following method to return a byte[] of the data using the PdfStamper

```
        public byte[] GetContentToMerge(string CADPDF, string TemplatePDF, string oldData, string newData, string jobNumber, string customer, string designer, string date)
    {

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(TemplatePDF);
            PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(CADPDF);

            // Use a Memory stream instead of a filestream 
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);

            //PSModel psModel = powerSHAPE.ActiveModel;

            try
            {

                AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

                fields.SetField("oldDataField", oldData);
                fields.SetField("newDataField", newData);
                fields.SetField("jobNumberField", jobNumber);
                fields.SetField("customerField", customer);
                fields.SetField("dateField", date);
                fields.SetField("designerField", designer);
                stamper.FormFlattening = false;

                PdfImportedPage page = stamper.GetImportedPage(reader2, 1);
                PdfContentByte cb;

                cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height);

                stamper.Close();
                reader.Close();
                reader2.Close();

                // The content you wanted to create is in a memory stream. 
                // It can bee appended to a PDF as a byte[] 
                byte[] ContentToAppend = ms.ToArray();
                return ContentToAppend;

            }
            catch
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Unable to merge drawing with template!");                    
            }

            stamper.Close();
        }

        // If we made it here, something went wrong.
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

Using that method, you can call it from a parent method and programmatically do the append.

```
        public void MergePDFs(string CADPDF, string TemplatePDF, string FinalPDF, string oldData, string newData, string jobNumber, string customer, string designer, string date)
    {
            using (Document oDoc = new Document())
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {

                PdfSmartCopy oPDF = new PdfSmartCopy(oDoc, ms);
                oDoc.Open();

                // If the FinalPDF file already exists, load it's data into the PDF 1st.
                if (File.Exists(FinalPDF))
                {
                    byte[] bytesFinalPDF = File.ReadAllBytes(FinalPDF);
                    oPDF.AddDocument(new PdfReader(bytesFinalPDF));
                }
                // If it doesn't exist, the oPDF is blank at this point.

                // Second  add the CAD and Template data to the PDF
                // We do this by calling the GetContentToMerge method which returns the byte array of data that was created using the stamper.
                byte[] ContentToAdd = GetContentToMerge(CADPDF, TemplatePDF, oldData, newData, jobNumber, customer, designer, date);
                if (ContentToAdd.Length > 0)
                {
                    oPDF.AddDocument(new PdfReader(ContentToAdd));
                }

                oDoc.Close();

                // Take whatever went into oPDF object's memory stream and write it to a file with path FinalPDF
                File.WriteAllBytes(FinalPDF, ms.ToArray());
            }
    }
```

** I didn't debug this 100%, so it might require some clean up on checking if files exist, read/write permissions, etc...

Comment: This looks like exactly what i need thank you very much!